# Overriding properties doesn't work

Tags: c#

My class `Ellipse` should inherit from my class `Shape` but I get this error message:

> Error 1 'ConsoleApplication3.Ellipse' does not implement inherited abstract member 'ConsoleApplication3.Shape.Perimeter.get'

I also get the error message that I'm hiding `Area`, a property in `Ellipse`.

Can anyone help me please?

My shape class looks like this:

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    //Protected constructor
    protected Shape(double length, double width)
    {
        _length = length;
        _width = width;
    }


    private double _length;
    private double _width;

    public abstract double Area
    {
        get;
    }
```

And my ellipse class is:

```
class Ellipse : Shape
{
    //Constructor
    public Ellipse(double length, double width)
        :base(length, width)
    {

    }

    //Egenskaper
    public override double Area
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.PI * Length * Width;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code for both classes?

Comment: I pasted your sample code into a console app, adding accessors for Length and Width, and it compiles fine.  Compare your sample code to your real code and you should get your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `override` modifier on the Area and Perimeter properties in your Ellipse class, e.g.

```
public override double Area { get; }

public override double Perimeter { get; }
```

A tip for you in Visual Studio, put the cursor inside the text 'Shape' (in your ellipse class) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>.  This should add stubs for members you haven't implemented

Comment: I have done that but it still doesnt work.

public override double Area
        {
            get
            {
                return Math.PI * Length * Width;
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

May be this is what you after as you have not declared Length , Width any where in your Ellipse class so you might be getting compilation errors, to compile this you need enhance visibility of _length and _width  properties of your base class Shape.

```
public abstract class Shape
{
  //Protected konstruktor
  protected Shape(double length, double width)
  {
    _length = length;
    _width = width;
  }

  // have these variables protected since you instantiate you child through the parent class.       

  protected double _length;
  protected double _width;

  public abstract double Area
  {
    get;
  }
}
class Ellipse : Shape
{
  //Konstruktor
  public Ellipse(double length, double width)
    : base(length, width)
  {

  }

  //Egenskaper
  public override double Area
  {
    get
    {
      // use the variable inherited since you only call the base class constructor.
      return Math.PI * _length * _width;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "you have not declared Length , Width any where in your Ellipse class"? Your answer looks exactly like my solution.

Comment: @HerrNilsson if can note two things 1) protected double _length; and protected double _width; in Shape class

Comment: 2)  public override double Area
          {
            get
            {
              return Math.PI * _length * _width;
            }
          }

Comment: -1 for putting up the same answer with only a change in variable where as you could have edited the question itself with a comment.

Comment: @Dumb He is having all sort of difficulty already, He can simply compare my code with his rather than me confusing by editing his question with my code. Have I done any wrong ? Is my answer wrong ?

Comment: @SurjitSamra Your answer is perfect. Dint mean to ridicule but when its so minute, either Highlight it correctly in your answer or edit his version and comment it. Would help everyone ! Sorry for the downvote. Will help you next time to get more upvotes ! Make the change clear to see !

Comment: @Dumb Yep got your update thanks , if you dont mind to change your name as you dont seem Dumb at all ;) May be something 'SuperSmart' :) will give others confidence